# Difference between srcset and media query?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, srcset

What is the difference between `srcset` and `media query`? Which is better and when to use them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`srcset` lets you load different (content) images depending on the media.

*media queries* let you apply different CSS rules depending on the media.

Use one for images and the other for CSS.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this** [**in-depth article about this.**](https://livefiredev.com/srcset-vs-media-queries-which-should-you-use-why/)

Since you are asking about both of these together, I am going to assume that you are asking about how to achieve the goal of "**responsive images**" (the correct sized image served to every device based on resolution) using both.

Now, you **could have some strategy of achieving this** (display none the img elements that are not needed for a particular screen size) using media queries. However, there **are a few down sides.**

Let me quote the above linked article:

> Media queries have limited support for pixel density. Because of this,
> images will not be properly selected on all devices & will look
> blurry. Also, unless you "lazy" load the images, the browser will load
> all sizes. (Even if they are set to display:none) This defeats the
> purpose. srcset does not have these problems.

Basically, **srcset is the better tool for the job** and is designed to solve this very problem.